# Euro sign in Bokeh HoverTool

Tags: python, bokeh

Python 3.10.
Bokeh 2.4.3

I have searched and searched but I can't find a solution.

I'm trying to get a euro sign (€) to appear in a Bokeh HoverTool tooltip.
The dollar sign is pretty easy to do:

```
hover.tooltips = [
        ('Post', '@Post'),
        ('Bedrag', '@Bedrag{$ 0.00}')
    ]
```

Changing the $ to a € doesn't do anything.

I've tried to somehow use the `PrintfTickFormatter` with `hover.formatters` but while the formatter works fine for one of the axis in the figure itself (`figVbar.yaxis[0].formatter = PrintfTickFormatter(format="€ %s")`), I can't get it to work with a hovertooltip.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: There is always [`CustomJSHover`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#customjshover)

Comment: If changing doesn't do anything, you're changing in the wrong place or you need to trigger some kind of code update in your test environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy modification do get this done is to specify the `formatters` and use the  [`PrintfTickFormatter`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#printftickformatter) in the Hovertool .

The definition of the HoverTool could look like this:

```
HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ('Post', '@Post'),
        ('Bedrag', '@Bedrag{€ %.2f}') # use the format for floats (with 2 digits)
    ],
    formatters={"@Bedrag": "printf"}, # activate the PrintfTickFormatter
)
```

**Minimal Example**

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
output_notebook()

source = ColumnDataSource({'index':[0,1,2], 'Post':[1,2,3],'Bedrag':[3,4,5]})

p=figure(width=300, height=300)

bar = p.vbar(x='index', top='Post', source=source, width=0.8)

p.add_tools(
            HoverTool(
                tooltips=[
        ('Post', '@Post'),
        ('Bedrag', '@Bedrag{€ %.2f}')
    ],
        formatters={"@Bedrag": "printf"},
        renderers=[bar],
    )
)

show(p)
```

**Output**

[image: customized HoverTool]